# javafx: How can the text in MenuButton be replaced instead of only being added

Tags: java, javafx

Here is my javafx code for creating a `MenuButton`:

```
 import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuButton;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class testGetText extends Application{


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
@Override
public void start(Stage arg0) throws Exception {
    Label l1 =new Label("Start");
    MenuButton b = new MenuButton("",l1);
    b.getStylesheets().add("resources/css/button.css");

    Label s = new Label("item"); 
    MenuItem item = new MenuItem("",s);
    b.getItems().add(item);
    item.setOnAction(e->{
        b.setText(null);
        b.setText(s.getText());
    ;});
    Pane p = new Pane();
    p.getChildren().addAll(b);
    Scene sc = new Scene(p);
    sc.getStylesheets().add("resources/css/button.css");
    arg0.setScene(sc);
    arg0.show();
}
}
```

The text "Start" in the button can only be added a "item" instead of being replaced, and I don't find method to remove the text in a `MenuButton` in oracle doc. How can the text in MenuButton be replaced instead of only being added?

Comment: Just using `... = new MenuButton("Start")` will suffice, I see no reason to add a Label as Graphics to the MenuButton ( and of course to MenuItem as well).

Comment: @JKostikiadis Acturally I was using css to give the text in `MenuButton` other color, but I cannot change color by directly coding the css of `-fx-text-fill: `

Comment: So the real question is how to change the Color of the choice texts in MenuButton ?

Comment: @JKostikiadis So I used `Label` to be able to change the color. If the color and the text can be both solved, that would be the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is wrong in my opinion. You shouldn't use Labels as Graphics nodes for the MenuButton & MenuItem. Instead use CSS to change the colors of the displayed text. Here is an example :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuButton;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestApplication extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        MenuItem menuItem1 = new MenuItem("Option 1");

        // parameters = "prompt" "Icon/Graphics/" "menuItem1"
        MenuButton menuButton = new MenuButton("Options", null, menuItem1);

        menuItem1.setOnAction(e -> {
            menuButton.setText(menuItem1.getText());
        });

        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.getChildren().addAll(menuButton);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

**CSS file :**

```
.menu-item > .label {
    -fx-text-fill: red;
}

.menu-button > .label {
    -fx-text-fill : red;
}
```

In case you want to keep your logic and keep using labels the way you do.. ( please don't :P ), in order to fix your problem you have to change the actual graphics nodes of the MenuButton everytime a MenuItem triggers an event. The way of doing that is this :

```
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Label promptLabel = new Label("Start");

        MenuButton menuButton = new MenuButton();
        menuButton.setGraphic(promptLabel);

        Label choice1Label = new Label("Choice 1");
        MenuItem menuItem1 = new MenuItem();
        menuItem1.setGraphic(choice1Label);

        menuButton.getItems().add(menuItem1);

        menuItem1.setOnAction(e -> {
            String text = ((Label) menuItem1.getGraphic()).getText();
            ((Label) menuButton.getGraphic()).setText((text));
        });

        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.getChildren().addAll(menuButton);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
```

I am sure just seeing the example above using Label will make you understand how bad idea this is, but still...